# loop parent record followed by children, parent and children etc

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen a few questions like this and variations of this but I am still confused as how to go about doing this. I have different dealers in different regions and want to list them by region in one long list.

**West Coast**
dealer 1 
dealer 2 
dealer 3

**East Coast** 
dealer 1 
dealer 2 
dealer 3

And so on...

I have a database table with a list of regions and another table with a list of dealers.

The dealer table has a column which contains the region id from the regions table so I can join the tables.

I tried this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `region_name`, `dealer_name` FROM `dealer_region` as `dr` INNER JOIN `dealers` as `d` ON dr.`id` = d.`region_id` GROUP BY `region_name`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dealer_name = $row['dealer_name'];
        $region_name = $row['region_name'];
        echo $region_name . "<br />" . $dealer_name . "<br />";
    }
}

$stmt->close();
```

But this only results in one dealer being shown under each region instead of all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "GROUP BY region_name", you should use ORDER BY region_name. GROUP BY should only be used with aggregate functions (SUM, MIN, MAX, COUNT...). With ORDER BY, you will get the dealers by region.

Slight modification to your code included:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("
SELECT region_name, dealer_name 
FROM dealer_region as dr 
  INNER JOIN dealers as d ON dr.id = d.region_id
  ORDER BY region_name
");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
$region_name = null;

if($numRows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (is_null($region_name) || $region_name != $row['region_name']) {
      $region_name = $row['region_name'];
      echo '<b>' . $region_name . '</b><br>';
    }
    echo $row['dealer_name'].'<br>';
    }
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: The problem with using ORDER BY is it gives me the region name, one dealer name, region name again, second dealer name and so on. Each region should only show once and then all the dealers listed underneath that region

Comment: because you need two loops. one that loops over the results of the regions, one that loops over the results of the dealers.

Comment: One just needs to check in the PHP code when the region changes and then act upon that. With the ORDER BY all dealers within the region comes after eachother and when the region changes, one can display it. Much more efficient than the serialized SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, you need to show the region once, and than a list of all dealers. What you are doing is showing per dealer also the region: because both are printed in the same loop.

In this situation it doesn't really make sense to use a join, since you don't need all the region information with each dealer.

in pseudo codo:

```
Select * from dealer_region
Loop over the results
    echo $regionname
    Select * from dealers where region_id = $dealerID
    Loop over the results
        echo $dealername
```

**Edit:** oke... query inside a loop is not eeh.. recommended

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dealer_region`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $regions[ $row['id'] ] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT *  FROM `dealers` ORDER BY `region_id`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dealers[ $row['region_id'] ][ $row['id'] ] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();

foreach( $dealers AS $regionID => $dealers_)
{
    echo '<b>'.$regions[ $regionID ].'</b>';
    foreach($dealers_ AS $dealerID => $dealer )
    {
        echo $dealer['dealer_name'];
    }
}
```

In case you want one query only, you need 3 loops...

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `region_name`, `dealer_name` FROM `dealer_region` as `dr` INNER JOIN `dealers` as `d` ON dr.`id` = d.`region_id`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[ $row['region_name'] ][] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();

foreach( $data AS $regionName => $dealers)
{
    echo '<b>'.$regionName .'</b>';
    foreach( $dealers AS $dealer )
    {
        echo $dealer['dealer_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Serializing the SQL makes unnecessary queries and is therefore not recommended. You can do all with a single query.